# Is the linear span of a countable set a complete subspace?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space with $\{v_i\} \subset V$ countable. Is this enough to conclude that $U := \operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{R}}(\{v_i\})$ is a complete subspace of $V$? (Surely this holds if $\{v_i\}$ is finite.)

Comment: A complete infinite-dimensional Banach space is always of uncountable dimension (in the sense of Hamel base).

Comment: In fact, such $U$ is complete *only* if it is finite dimensional.  You can prove this with the Baire category theorem. So the answer is basically "never, except in trivial cases".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of all real sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms is the span of the countable set of sequences with just  one $1$ and all other terms $0$. It is dense in the Hilbert space of square summable sequences, so not complete.